# Could someone please let me know what this download is- "sha256"

Tags: installation

I apologise in advance for the stupidity.

Could someone let me know what I have just downloaded from the blender.org site. I had clicked on the "sha256" by accident and something just downloaded, I have not got a clue what it is could some let me know

Thanks

Comment: Sha256 is an encryption protocol used as a  checksum that is used to verify that the file you downloaded is the exact same as the file as on the site (the one you downloaded from). If your file got corrupted during download (or if someone tried to sneak a nasty file in), you will notice a difference in the checksum numbers. This is used mainly for security verification to make sure the file you got was the correct one.

Comment: This question kinda explains what this sha256 is https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/189000/how-to-verify-the-checksum-of-a-downloaded-file-pgp-sha-etc Like @ChristopherBennett wrote it's just used to make sure that the file with actual blender installer didn't arrive to your PC corrupted/broken/hacked/swapped.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. I just got a bit confused because I couldn't open the file up and have never heard of the term. So, its just file of text to reference to check that you've made a legitimate/authentic file download right

Comment: @Stack151 Correct

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2 I guess this is a XY problem: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY-Problem You do not get blender installed on your machine?